# Can't change inode directory in plasma

Tags: kde, manjaro, nautilus, inode, plasma

I am using KDE in Manjaro. I need to set Nautilus for my default and inode directory. I used some commands, and it didn't work.

```
$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
org.kde.dolphin.desktop

$ xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search

$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
org.kde.dolphin.desktop
```

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: After running the command to change the default, what does `echo $?` print?

Comment: now it shows nautilus as the default. But how to change the accessibility of other applications to open file manager via nautilus